# How to put a value in external string

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dart file that has all my strings (like strings.xml in Java)
How can I write a dynamic string?

```
Texts {
  static const String welcome_msg = "Hello $user";
}
```

and in another Dart file, I want to have something like this:

```
Texts.welcome_message("Username");
```

P.S: I prefer to do it without writing a function

thanks, I'm apologizing if I describe what I meant bad

Comment: Can you please give more details with examples for your question? Because it looks like not understandable.

Comment: `class UserName extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Texts.welcome_msg("my_username") );
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a method with parameter for your case to work:

```
class Texts {
  static String welcomeMessage(String user) => 'Hello $user';
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
Texts.welcomeMessage('John Doe');
```

Comment: I think it should be `static` btw, so we can call it from any where without instantiate the class

Comment: It's good if I have to use method, "thanks"